# How to get a flat, non-interpolated color when using vertex shaders

Tags: c++, opengl, interpolation, shader

Is there a way to achieve this (OpenGL 2.1)? If I draw lines like this

```
glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
glBegin(GL_LINES);
  glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
  glVertex3fv(bottomLeft);
  glVertex3fv(topRight);

  glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
  glVertex3fv(topRight);
  glVertex3fv(topLeft);
  .
  .
  (draw a square)
  .
  .
glEnd();
```

I get the desired result (a different colour for each edge) but I want to be able to calculate the fragment values in a shader. If I do the same after setting up my shader program I always get interpolated colors between vertices. Is there a way around this? (would be even better if I could get the same results using quads)

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand when you say "using quads", do you mean gl_line_loop ? There's no such thing like gl_line_quads in OpenGL.
What do you want exactly to draw?

Comment: I want to draw a square with different color lines as the code suggests. I mean if I used GL_QUADS then there would be less code overhead, which would be better than using GL_LINES.

Comment: GL_QUADS will draw a pixel filled quad. If you use GL_LINES OpenGL will draw only the edges of the quad. So not the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the interpolation between vertice attributes inside a primitive (e.g. color in a line segment in your case) you'll need to pass the same color twice, so end up duplicating your geometry:

```
 v0             v1          v2
 x--------------x-----------x
```

(v0 is made of structs p0 and c0, v1 of p1 and c1 etc..)

**For drawing the line with color interpolation:**

```
glBegin(GL_LINES);
//draw first segment
glColor3fv(&c0); glVertex3fv(&p0);
glColor3fv(&c1); glVertex3fv(&p1);
//draw second segment
glColor3fv(&c1); glVertex3fv(&p1);
glColor3fv(&c2); glVertex3fv(&p2);
glEnd();
```

**For drawing without interpolation:**

```
glBegin(GL_LINES);
//draw first segment
glColor3fv(&c0); glVertex3fv(&p0);
glColor3fv(&c0); glVertex3fv(&p1);
//draw second segment
glColor3fv(&c1); glVertex3fv(&v1);
glColor3fv(&c1); glVertex3fv(&v2);
glEnd();
```

Note this mean you can no longer use `GL_x_STRIP` topology, since you don't want to share attributes inside a primitive.

Comment: Ok thanks. I understand, I need to do the same computation in each vertex on the line.