# webgl shaders and texture filters

Tags: opengl-es, webgl

I'm not that experienced with WebGL(Guess the same problem would translate in OpenGL). I'm rendering my objects using a vertex and a fragment shader. Basically all the shaders do is get the input color for a vertex and just pass it unchanged until the fragment, so steps:

```
In vertex shader, amongst other things:

attribute vec4 aVertexColor;
varying vec4 vColor;

.................
vColor = aVertexColor;
..................

In shader color:

varying vec4 vColor;

...........
gl_FragColor = vColor;
```

Now this works fine. However from what I can see the interpolation for the fragments defaults to linear and I would want to change it to nearest. Now what I;m trying is to do:

```
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
```

But this seems to have no effect, even if I change the gl.NEAREST with gl.LINEAR for example, that doesn't change absolutely nothing as far as I can tell. Does the shader somehow overwrite some stuff and that's why I dont get the desired effect?[image: result image]

Now I;ve attached the result I'm getting. Now what I'm targeting for is to have the triangle in 3 areas of different colors(the same as the vertices). So in my case I aim for ~1.3 blue, ~1.3 green, ~1.3 red without any kind of intermediate colors. Any hints?

Here is what I want to obtain:

[image: Desired result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want I don't believe is possible. Varying values are always interpolated, you can't override it to use nearest. To achieve your desired result I think you'll have to just draw the 3 polygons separately.

You could also use some pixel shader trickery in this very specific case to find the maximum component of RGB, set it to 1, and set the other two components to zero, but that wouldn't work for any other colors.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the input. I'll just have to find some other solution to my problem then. :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you misunderstood the `Nearest Filtering` subject. If you use a texture, you pickup the nearest texture pixel's color instead of a blended with neighbour pixels color. But it doesn't help you to have constant, not blended colors between vertices using your approach. I guess what you want is something like below.

[How to get a flat, non-interpolated color when using vertex shaders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685094/how-to-get-a-flat-non-interpolated-color-when-using-vertex-shaders)

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'm guessing I have it all wrong, however I don't really think that the link you provided would help. I don't want each line with a different color. I've updated my answer with a visualization of what I'm trying to achieve.